# Why do my RSA values for p, q, e = 3 result in unsuccessful decryption?

Tags: python, rsa

I'm actually trying to solve cryptopals set 5 challenge 39. I'm trying to implement RSA for some larger primes p and q, e = 3. I've been puzzled over this for *hours*.

To generate primes, I'm hitting an API to get each prime. I keep generating p until gcd(p - 1, e) == 1, and then repeat for q until gcd(q - 1, e) == 1. I've tested for gcd((p - 1) * (q - 1), e) == 1, too. For example, I end up with p == 16226322033026808497, and q == 14712923008023747557.

I then do the simple RSA math to calculate the other terms, encrypt message 42 (no padding), decrypt that cipher, and compare the resulting plain to the original message. I've generated many, many ps and qs, and it never matches.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work, and help me generate some good parameters, please?

Python:

```
p = 16226322033026808497
q = 14712923008023747557
e = 3
print(f'1 == gcd(p - 1, e) == {gcd(p - 1, e)}')
print(f'1 == gcd(p - 1, e) == {gcd(q - 1, e)}')

phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
print(f'phi == {phi}')
print(f'1 == gcd(phi, e) == {gcd(phi, e)}')
n = p * q
print(f'n == {n}')
d = invmod(e, phi)
print(f'd == {d}')
print(f'1 == (d * e) % phi == {(d * e) % phi}')

m = 42
c = pow(m, e, n);
print(f'c == m**e % n == {c}')
p = pow(c, d, n);
print(f'p == c**d % n == {p}')
```

Output:

```
1 == gcd(p - 1, e) == 1
1 == gcd(p - 1, e) == 1
phi == 238736626775322802092761613952260035776
1 == gcd(phi, e) == 1
n == 238736626775322802123700858993310591829
d == 159157751183548534728507742634840023851
1 == (d * e) % phi == 1
c == m**e % n == 74088
p == c**d % n == 145835535613124975159078105657928869819
```

Comment: Choose a `p` and `q` small enough to work through it by hand, then compare your results with what your program outputs. That should help you to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: I have tested with p = 11, q = 23, e = 3. No problem. I found p = 3372213049, q = 3372213067, e = 6557 somewhere. No problem, but I want e = 3. Plus I'm running all the checks I know of (for coprime) in the code above - what am I missing?

Comment: Well, it would help if you chose `p` and `q` as primes: your `p == 1969260091 * 8239806467` and your `q == 1756690123 * 8375366159`.

Comment: How did you do the primality test?!

Comment: I used `sympy.primefactors`.

Comment: OK, the API is giving me non-prime numbers, then. What a prank! I'll try to generate differently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API that I used to generate primes was in fact giving composites, which prevents meaningful decryption. Generating with a more reliable source, I find p == 18015945217661527751, q == 11788823512629961979, for example, which are actually prime. And I can now successfully decrypt back to the original message.

I've found that https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/random3 gives some reasonable primes.

Comment: *...The API...* what API?

Comment: I was hitting the endpoint backing https://bigprimes.org/RSA-challenge, but I made a mistake in selecting it. It was an endpoint giving random "RSA challenges" ie composites, not an endpoint giving random primes.